# Headers Already Sent Error with no headers being sent

Tags: php

Getting this stupid error over and over with absolutely no headers being sent other than this one over and over again ( prints 5 times each time page is ran )

```
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/xx/public_html/xx/index.php:1) in /home/xx/public_html/xx/index.php on line 1
```

My index.php:

```
<?php header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');
            require("load.php");?>
            <!DOCTYPE HTML>
            <html>
            <head>
```

My load.php:

```
<?php
define("ABS_PATH", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
include_once (ABS_PATH .'/assets/x/la.php');
require(ABS_PATH ."/assets/x/go.php");
///some more variables;?>
```

My la.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Cache-control: private'); // IE 6 FIX

if(isSet($_GET['lang']))
{
$lang = $_GET['lang'];
}
/// more code?>
```

I have no idea what's going on.

EDIT: Found the issue. There was a freaking single space after my `?>`. I removed it and voila, it is now fixed. Thanks obama

Comment: `header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');` Why is this line required at the top of your index.php page?

Comment: Headers are sent when you output anything into a page. `session_Start` also should be at the top of a page.

Comment: You probably have some whitespace characters before or after your php-tags. If there is only PHP content in a file, remove the end-tag. And check that the file starts with <?php and no whitespace before. You should also check that you have saved your file with UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: @Akshay Site is in german

Comment: Got it, check out my answer.

Comment: @u_mulder yep, but the file is actually empty. Have no idea what's going on

Comment: A lot of PHP projects introduce a standard of no closing `?>` to avoid this problem.  PHP will run just fine without it (so long s there's no non-php code in there), so it's safe to do and will help you avoid this stuff in the future.

Comment: The definitive SO answer about this? [How to fix “Headers already sent” error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You must use session_start before any headers have been sent.

Put `session_start;` above `header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');`

Answer (score 0):

I see a whitespace here. Try this code.

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');
require("load.php");?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
```

Also, your session must be started before you send any headers.

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'header' (T_STRING)` is the error im getting with your solution

Comment: I forgot to add a `;` in swiftness. Try again, please.